# Mac NetInstall does not send booter on specific devices

Tags: mac, netboot

Using Mac Server on 10.9, with only NetInstall working (we use InfoBlox for DHCP) I can successfully NetBoot to our only image from a iMac Pro (Core2Duo), but not from a MacBook Pro (Intel i7, ~2012).

- I captured the NBI on the newer MacBook Pro (Deploystudio Netboot Set)
- Both devices list the boot image in the boot options menu at startup.
- Both devices allow me to SELECT the image.
- Both devices send a BSDP ACK[SELECT] to the server.
- Server sends both devices at least an ACK pktsize 300 to the correct IP.

The MacBook Pro decides, after all this, that it will just boot to the regular local disk, which is not what should happen. Whereas the main iMac boots to the network disk (Apple Logo with mini spinning globe).

Does anyone have any ideas why the MacBook Pro does not boot, considering it is communicating with the server?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Although using only NetInstall. My problem was cause by the fact that the Netboot image (folder)and files inside of it had incorrect permissions (for instace the booter files had no access to the everyone group.
After I fixed the entire folder permission manually Netboot worked.
I hope this helps you.